# Apple Mach-O Linker Error when trying to use RestKit

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoapods-1.2

I installed cocoapods and it shown as below

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer (0.6.1)
Using RKValueTransformers (1.1.3)
Using RestKit (0.27.0)
Using SOCKit (1.1)
Using TransitionKit (2.2.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 5 total pods installed.
```

Also I put '-ObjC' and '$(inherited)' inside 'other linker flags' and there are

```
${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AFNetworking
${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Bolts
${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer
${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/RKValueTransformers
${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/RestKit 
${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/SOCKit
${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public
```

already inside 'Header Search Path' with all non-recursive. Every time I tried to run the project it gave me 'linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'. And also when I changed them to recursive, the 'linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)' occured. The podfile is

```
platform :ios, '10.2'
target 'Fpace' do
pod 'RestKit'
end
```

Comment: Are opening the Xcode project *or* workspace? You should be using the workspace...

Comment: You mean the changed path? Sorry for the silly question, I just a new starter of objective C.

Comment: I meant opening the `Fpace.xcworkspace` file (or something like that), which contains *both* your project and the generated cocoapods project.

Comment: Yes, I just tried to open the Xcode project instead of workspace. When I opened the workspace and run, it worked. Thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: I just posted my suggestion as an answer below to help future readers. Please select it as the accepted answer, ok? Thanks man and good luck on your app ;-)

Comment: Ofcourse, I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you opening the Xcode **project** or **workspace**? You must always use the `*.workspace` file in [CocoaPods based projects](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html).

In your specific case, that should be the  `Fpace.workspace` bundle.